# Symfony custom type: how to handle the process of transforming form data into entity attributes

Tags: php, forms, symfony, jquery-select2, addeventlistener

I am looking forward to build a custom form type where I could use the entity behaviour but also create a new simple entity if the selected option does not correspond to an existing entity.
I am using jquery select2 on the client side for that matter.

On the server side, from within the formType, how can handle by myself how the form data is converted into entity attributes ? i.e. how does symfony convert a select field into entities ?

I am looking for something like

```
    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::XXX_SUBMIT,
        function(FormEvent $event){
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $entity= $form->getData();
            $value= $form->getFieldValue('fieldName');
            $entity->setTag($this->em->getRepository('Tag')->findOneByName('value'))
        }
    );
```

I had no chance in finding how it is done, any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: This may not be useful to know, but I gave up mixing entities with forms.  I prefer to validate on an unmanaged model before persist/updating to the entities precisely because of the over complications of using an entity as a data placeholder.

Comment: I suggest using a bit different approach. Form events in Symfony2 Forms component are for extending Form (depending on data set or submitted), but if you want to transform data - you should use DataTransformers.

Comment: Yes, I thought about data transformers but I think it won't work: I need to persist a new entity (not flush it) and associate the newly created entity (a tag in my example) to the parent entity. If I'm not mistaking, the datatransformer will be called and then symfony will throw an error as the new entity won't be found in the database.